# Radix2 Fast Fourier Transform implemented in C++

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, signal-processing, complex-numbers

> *Note: If you don't know much about Fourier transform algorithms, a simple review of whether I am doing anything inefficient with C++ in general would be appreciated.*

I've been working on implementing an efficient Radix2 Fast Fourier Transform in C++ and I seem to have hit a roadblock. I have optimized it in every possible way I can think of and it is very fast, but when comparing it to the Numpy FFT in Python it is still significantly slower. Note that my FFT is not done in-place, but neither is the Python implementation so I should be able to achieve at least the same efficiency as Numpy.

I've already taken advantage of symmetry when the input is a real signal which allows the use of an N/2 point FFT for an N-length real signal, and I also pre-compute all of the twiddle factors and optimize the twiddle factor calculation so redundant twiddle factors are not re-calculated.

**The code:**

```
#include <cassert>
#include <complex>
#include <vector>

// To demonstrate runtime
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

static std::vector<std::complex<double>> FFTRadix2(const std::vector<std::complex<double>>& x, const std::vector<std::complex<double>>& W);
static bool IsPowerOf2(size_t x);
static size_t ReverseBits(const size_t x, const size_t n);

std::vector<std::complex<double>> FFT(const std::vector<double>& x)
{
    size_t N = x.size();

    // Radix2 FFT requires length of the input signal to be a power of 2
    // TODO: Implement other algorithms for when N is not a power of 2
    assert(IsPowerOf2(N));

    // Taking advantage of symmetry the FFT of a real signal can be computed
    // using a single N/2-point complex FFT. Split the input signal into its
    // even and odd components and load the data into a single complex vector.
    std::vector<std::complex<double>> x_p(N / 2);
    for (size_t n = 0; n < N / 2; ++n)
    {
        // x_p[n] = x[2n] + jx[2n + 1]
        x_p[n] = std::complex<double>(x[2 * n], x[2 * n + 1]);
    }

    // Pre-calculate twiddle factors
    std::vector<std::complex<double>> W(N / 2);
    std::vector<std::complex<double>> W_p(N / 4);
    for (size_t k = 0; k < N / 2; ++k)
    {
        W[k] = std::polar(1.0, -2 * M_PI * k / N);

        // The N/2-point complex DFT uses only the even twiddle factors
        if (k % 2 == 0)
        {
            W_p[k / 2] = W[k];
        }
    }

    // Perform the N/2-point complex FFT
    std::vector<std::complex<double>> X_p = FFTRadix2(x_p, W_p);

    // Extract the N-point FFT of the real signal from the results 
    std::vector<std::complex<double>> X(N);
    X[0] = X_p[0].real() + X_p[0].imag();
    for (size_t k = 1; k < N / 2; ++k)
    {
        // Extract the FFT of the even components
        auto A = std::complex<double>(
            (X_p[k].real() + X_p[N / 2 - k].real()) / 2,
            (X_p[k].imag() - X_p[N / 2 - k].imag()) / 2);

        // Extract the FFT of the odd components
        auto B = std::complex<double>(
            (X_p[N / 2 - k].imag() + X_p[k].imag()) / 2,
            (X_p[N / 2 - k].real() - X_p[k].real()) / 2);

        // Sum the results and take advantage of symmetry
        X[k] = A + W[k] * B;
        X[k + N / 2] = A - W[k] * B;
    }

    return X;
}

std::vector<std::complex<double>> FFT(const std::vector<std::complex<double>>& x)
{
    size_t N = x.size();

    // Radix2 FFT requires length of the input signal to be a power of 2
    // TODO: Implement other algorithms for when N is not a power of 2
    assert(IsPowerOf2(N));

    // Pre-calculate twiddle factors
    std::vector<std::complex<double>> W(N / 2);
    for (size_t k = 0; k < N / 2; ++k)
    {
        W[k] = std::polar(1.0, -2 * M_PI * k / N);
    }

    return FFTRadix2(x, W);
}

static std::vector<std::complex<double>> FFTRadix2(const std::vector<std::complex<double>>& x, const std::vector<std::complex<double>>& W)
{
    size_t N = x.size();

    // Radix2 FFT requires length of the input signal to be a power of 2
    assert(IsPowerOf2(N));

    // Calculate how many stages the FFT must compute
    size_t stages = static_cast<size_t>(log2(N));

    // Pre-load the output vector with the input data using bit-reversed indexes
    std::vector<std::complex<double>> X(N);
    for (size_t n = 0; n < N; ++n)
    {
        X[n] = x[ReverseBits(n, stages)];
    }

    // Calculate the FFT one stage at a time and sum the results
    for (size_t stage = 1; stage <= stages; ++stage)
    {
        size_t N_stage = static_cast<size_t>(std::pow(2, stage));
        size_t W_offset = static_cast<size_t>(std::pow(2, stages - stage));
        for (size_t k = 0; k < N; k += N_stage)
        {
            for (size_t n = 0; n < N_stage / 2; ++n)
            {
                auto tmp = X[k + n];
                X[k + n] = tmp + W[n * W_offset] * X[k + n + N_stage / 2];
                X[k + n + N_stage / 2] = tmp - W[n * W_offset] * X[k + n + N_stage / 2];
            }
        }
    }

    return X;
}

// Returns true if x is a power of 2
static bool IsPowerOf2(size_t x)
{
    return x && (!(x & (x - 1)));
}

// Given x composed of n bits, returns x with the bits reversed
static size_t ReverseBits(const size_t x, const size_t n)
{
    size_t xReversed = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        xReversed = (xReversed << 1U) | ((x >> i) & 1U);
    }

    return xReversed;
}

int main()
{
    size_t N = 16777216;
    std::vector<double> x(N);

    int f_s = 8000;
    double t_s = 1.0 / f_s;

    for (size_t n = 0; n < N; ++n)
    {
        x[n] = std::sin(2 * M_PI * 1000 * n * t_s)
            + 0.5 * std::sin(2 * M_PI * 2000 * n * t_s + 3 * M_PI / 4);
    }

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto X = FFT(x);
    auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(stop - start);

    std::cout << duration.count() << std::endl;
}
```

**Output (running a few times and averaging):**

> 3671677

*This was compiled in Visual Studio 2019 in Release mode with the* `/O2`*,* `/Oi` *and* `/Ot` *optimization compiler flags to try and squeeze as much speed as possible out of it.*

---

A comparable snippet of Python code that uses the Numpy FFT is shown below:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime

N = 16777216
f_s = 8000.0
t_s = 1/f_s

t = np.arange(0, N*t_s, t_s)
y = np.sin(2*np.pi*1000*t) + 0.5*np.sin(2*np.pi*2000*t + 3*np.pi/4)

start = datetime.datetime.now()
Y = np.fft.fft(y)
stop = datetime.datetime.now()
duration = stop - start

print(duration.total_seconds()*1e6)
```

**Output (running a few times and averaging):**

> 2100411.0

---

As you can see, the Python implementation is still faster by about 43%, but I can't think of any ways my implementation can be improved.

From what I understand, the Numpy version is actually implemented with C code underneath so I'm not terribly disappointed in the performance of my own code, but it still leaves me wondering what I am missing that I could still do better?

Comment: Can you give a hint about the used C++ standard (11, 14, 17) Can you use additional libraries such as gsl or abseil?

Comment: @miscco, C++11 is currently used but C++17 is available. Additional libraries are not out of the question. If they are available through the Conan package manager that would be a huge plus. Also it is important that it stays cross platform compatible so OS specific libraries are a no go.

Comment: Radix 2 is a slow algorithm by today's standards

Comment: You're only letting MSVC's auto-vectorize with SSE2?  I'd at least try letting it use AVX2 and maybe a fast-math option.  Or preferably a compiler like gcc or clang with `-O3 -march=native -ffast-math`.  Or if you have ICC it's well known for good auto-vectorization.  NumPy might well be manually vectorized for SSE2 and AVX / AVX2, with intrinsics like `_mm_shuffle_ps()` for SIMD vectors.  And `_mm_shuffle_epi8` for bit-reversal using a lookup table for 4-bit chunks.  Plain portable ISO C++ can't represent/expose a lot of useful things that modern CPUs can do.

Comment: @ScottSeidman, can you provide the names of any faster algorithms? As far as I am aware Radix 2 is essentially the fastest you can get but comes with a restriction that your input length is a power of 2.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks that sounds like some good advice. I'm trying to keep this as portable as possible so portability is one of the main restrictions here. It doesn't have to be lightning fast, but I just want to squeeze as much out of it as I can without having to write any platform specific code.

Comment: FFTW, for one example

Comment: Ok, then you have to realize that by limiting yourself to pure ISO C++, and/or by not even enabling AVX+FMA for the compiler to use, you're leaving significant performance on the table on modern CPUs.  That's a tradeoff you sometimes want to make when performance isn't critical and you want a single portable binary.  Many other FFT libraries have decided that performance *is* critical and use runtime dispatching to select an optimized version based on what the current CPU can do, or can be statically compiled to use AVX + FMA.

Comment: Writing portable code that can auto-vectorize nicely with (with SSE2 or AVX + FMA, or ARM NEON, or PowerPC Altivec) is possible for some problems, though.  So at least try enabling AVX+FMA for your compiler to give it a chance against manually-vectorized runtime-dispatching FFT libraries.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I'll look into that. I've never even heard of auto-vectorization which shows how inexperienced I am haha. Sounds like it could make a significant difference.

Comment: Thank you everyone for all of the very helpful advice. So far after taking a bunch of the advice while still keeping everything generic and cross-platform compatible I've managed to cut down the runtime to about 2.15 million microseconds. (Although my computer is a bit inconsistent so I'm not sure how accurate my results are.) I am still investigating some of the improvements suggested by @harold and imagine I can still get significantly better performance once I do a little more research and get a better understanding of some things!

Comment: Is it possible to swap the loop order for k and n? The W[n * W_offset] could be cached in a variable for the inner loop. Also you can cache W[n * W_offset] * X[k + n + N_stage / 2]; in a variable to avoid double calculation (although the compiler might do that for you).

Comment: @lalala, I just tried switching the loop order and to my surprise it actually drastically increased the runtime! Not sure  why. I have done your second suggestion though because the compiler was not doing that for me and it sped things up a bit.

Comment: @ScottSeidnan, I'm fairly certain FFTW is implemented using a Radix2 algorithm when the input is a length that is a power of 2, but it's significantly faster because it's super optimized for the specific hardware that it gets compiled on. FFTW is not just one algorithm. It is implemented with many algorithms and the best algorithm is selected based on both the length of the input signal and the detected hardware.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Putting this through the built-in profiler reveals some hot spots. Perhaps surprisingly: `ReverseBits`. It's not the biggest thing in the list, but it is significant while it shouldn't be.

You could use one of the many alternate ways to implement `ReverseBits`, or the sequence of bit-reversed indexes (which does not require reversing all the indexes), or the overall bit-reversal permutation (which does not require bit reversals).

For example here is a way to compute the sequence of bit-reversed indexes without explicitly reversing any index:

```
for (size_t n = 0, rev = 0; n < N; ++n)
{
    X[n] = x[rev];
    size_t change = n ^ (n + 1);
#if _WIN64
    rev ^= change << (__lzcnt64(change) - (64 - stages));
#else
    rev ^= change << (__lzcnt(change) - (32 - stages));
#endif
}
```

On my PC, that reduces the time from around 2.8 million microseconds to 2.3 million microseconds.

This trick works by using that the XOR between adjacent indexes is a mask of ones up to and including the least significant zero (the +1 carries through the least significant set bits and into that least significant zero), which has a form that can be reversed by just shifting it. The reversed mask is then the XOR between adjacent reversed indexes, so applying it to the current reversed index with XOR increments it.

`__lzcnt64` and `_WIN64` are for MSVC, you could use more preprocessor tricks to find the right intrinsic and bitness-detection for the current compiler. Leading zero count can be avoided by using `std::bitset` and its `count` method:

```
size_t change = n ^ (n + 1);
std::bitset<64> bits(~change);
rev ^= change << (bits.count() - (64 - stages));
```

`count` is recognized by GCC and Clang as an intrinsic for `popcnt`, but it seems not by MSVC, so it is not reliable for high performance scenarios.

Secondly, there is a repeated expression: `W[n * W_offset] * X[k + n + N_stage / 2]`. The compiler is often relied on to remove such duplication, but here it didn't happen. Factoring that out reduced the time to under 2 million microseconds.

Computing the twiddle factors takes a bit more time than it needs to. They are powers of the first non-trivial twiddle factor, and could be computed iteratively that way. This suffers from some build-up of inaccuracy, which could be improved by periodically resetting to the proper value computed by `std::polar`. For example,

```
auto twiddle_step = std::polar(1.0, -2.0 * M_PI / N);
auto twiddle_current = std::polar(1.0, 0.0);
for (size_t k = 0; k < N / 2; ++k)
{
    if ((k & 0xFFF) == 0)
        twiddle_current = std::polar(1.0, -2.0 * M_PI * k / N);
    W[k] = twiddle_current;
    twiddle_current *= twiddle_step;

    // The N/2-point complex DFT uses only the even twiddle factors
    if (k % 2 == 0)
    {
        W_p[k / 2] = W[k];
    }
}
```

On my PC that reduces the time from hovering around 1.95 million µs to around 1.85 million µs, not a huge difference but easily measurable.

More advanced: use SSE3 for the main calculation, for example (not well tested, but seems to work so far)

```
__m128d w_real = _mm_set1_pd(W[n * W_offset].real());
__m128d w_imag = _mm_set1_pd(W[n * W_offset].imag());
__m128d z = _mm_loadu_pd(reinterpret_cast<double*>(&X[k + n + N_stage / 2]));
__m128d z_rev = _mm_shuffle_pd(z, z, 1);
__m128d t = _mm_addsub_pd(_mm_mul_pd(w_real, z), _mm_mul_pd(w_imag, z_rev));

__m128d x = _mm_loadu_pd(reinterpret_cast<double*>(&X[k + n]));
__m128d t1 = _mm_add_pd(x, t);
__m128d t2 = _mm_sub_pd(x, t);
_mm_storeu_pd(reinterpret_cast<double*>(&X[k + n]), t1);
_mm_storeu_pd(reinterpret_cast<double*>(&X[k + n + N_stage / 2]), t2);
```

That takes it from 1.85 million µs down to around 1.6 million µs on my PC.

---

Using a different algorithm, Stockham algorithm the version from [List-8](http://wwwa.pikara.ne.jp/okojisan/otfft-en/optimization1.html) and some miscellaneous things, the time goes down to 0.9 million µs. It's a huge win already and this is not the best version of the algorithm. The linked website has faster versions with fancier tricks and SIMD too, so it's there if you want it. As a bonus, no bit reversing is used at all, so no need for a compiler-specific intrinsic.

The real work happens here: (taken from the linked website)

```
void fft0(int n, int s, bool eo, complex_t* x, complex_t* y)
// n  : sequence length
// s  : stride
// eo : x is output if eo == 0, y is output if eo == 1
// x  : input sequence(or output sequence if eo == 0)
// y  : work area(or output sequence if eo == 1)
{
    const int m = n / 2;
    const double theta0 = 2 * M_PI / n;

    if (n == 2) {
        complex_t* z = eo ? y : x;
        for (int q = 0; q < s; q++) {
            const complex_t a = x[q + 0];
            const complex_t b = x[q + s];
            z[q + 0] = a + b;
            z[q + s] = a - b;
        }
    }
    else if (n >= 4) {
        for (int p = 0; p < m; p++) {
            const complex_t wp = complex_t(cos(p*theta0), -sin(p*theta0));
            for (int q = 0; q < s; q++) {
                const complex_t a = x[q + s * (p + 0)];
                const complex_t b = x[q + s * (p + m)];
                y[q + s * (2 * p + 0)] = a + b;
                y[q + s * (2 * p + 1)] = (a - b) * wp;
            }
        }
        fft0(n / 2, 2 * s, !eo, y, x);
    }
}

void fft(int n, complex_t* x) // Fourier transform
// n : sequence length
// x : input/output sequence
{
    complex_t* y = new complex_t[n];
    fft0(n, 1, 0, x, y);
    delete[] y;
    // scaling removed because OP doesn't do it either
    //for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) x[k] /= n;
}
```

And here is that wrapper to do a Real FFT with a Complex FFT with half the number of points,

```
std::vector<std::complex<double>> FFT2(const std::vector<double>& x)
{
    size_t N = x.size();

    // Radix2 FFT requires length of the input signal to be a power of 2
    // TODO: Implement other algorithms for when N is not a power of 2
    assert(IsPowerOf2(N));

    // Taking advantage of symmetry the FFT of a real signal can be computed
    // using a single N/2-point complex FFT. Split the input signal into its
    // even and odd components and load the data into a single complex vector.
    std::vector<std::complex<double>> x_p(N / 2);
    std::copy(x.data(), x.data() + x.size(), reinterpret_cast<double*>(x_p.data()));

    fft(N / 2, x_p.data());

    // Extract the N-point FFT of the real signal from the results 
    std::vector<std::complex<double>> X(N);
    X[0] = x_p[0].real() + x_p[0].imag();
    auto twiddle_step = std::polar(1.0, -2.0 * M_PI / N);
    auto twiddle_current = twiddle_step;
    for (size_t k = 1; k < N / 2; ++k)
    {
        auto Wk = twiddle_current;
        // Extract the FFT of the even components
        auto A = std::complex<double>(
            (x_p[k].real() + x_p[N / 2 - k].real()) / 2,
            (x_p[k].imag() - x_p[N / 2 - k].imag()) / 2);

        // Extract the FFT of the odd components
        auto B = std::complex<double>(
            (x_p[N / 2 - k].imag() + x_p[k].imag()) / 2,
            (x_p[N / 2 - k].real() - x_p[k].real()) / 2);

        // Sum the results and take advantage of symmetry
        X[k] = A + Wk * B;
        X[k + N / 2] = A - Wk * B;

        twiddle_current *= twiddle_step;
    }

    return X;
}
```

Using `std::copy` was faster than a manual loop, and not storing the twiddles was also faster. Of course I used the fast twiddle factor generation scheme (without resets this time as per the comments, of course that's easy to put back in). Avoiding the copy altogether would obviously be better, but then the input data will be turned into its FFT instead of leaving it read-only, it's not a drop-in replacement.

Extracting the Real FFT takes a significant portion of the total time by the way.

Comment: Is there a way that doesn't involve preprocessor tricks to make this cross platform compatible? I'd prefer to avoid using the preprocessor although it's not completely out of the question.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 I added an alternative. You could try one of the other permutation algorithms to avoid this problem altogether.

Comment: Thanks this all looks like very useful advice! I'll try to take advantage of some of it and let you know how it goes. Out of curiosity, how did you know the compiler didn't factor out the duplicated code?

Comment: @tjwrona1992 by proof-reading the assembly code, painful as it was

Comment: Do you know where I can find examples of other permutation algorithms to do the bit reversal?

Comment: @tjwrona1992 some are described in [Bit Reversal on
Uniprocessors](https://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/93/HPL-93-89.pdf)

Comment: That last part goes way over my head but is definitely very interesting. I'm sure I will be revisiting this when I have more experience! I do have one question about the bit reversal though. Is there any way to do it without the hardcoded 64? Wouldn't this break if it were compiled in a 32 bit environment?

Comment: @tjwrona1992 yes good point, would you accept working with `uint32_t`? It can be made size-adaptive but at the cost of more verbosity..

Comment: Hmmm... when I actually use this I don't think I will need 100% maximum efficiency for it to still be very useful so I would prefer to be size adaptive as long as it is more efficient than the implementation I have in the question as asked.

Comment: Also even with the cumulative error if you just iteratively calculate the twiddle factors, with any reasonably sized FFT will it make the results noticeably off if you don't correct for it?

Comment: @tjwrona1992 it's a visible difference if you print the numbers to 10 digits or so (at the size used in the benchmark), if you're OK with that you could also look into doing the whole thing with `float`, the memory savings alone would already make it faster and with SSE there are further benefits

Comment: For a cross platform / both 32 and 64 bit solution would there be any issues using the `bitset` style way of doing things with `std::bitset<sizeof(size_t) * 8>` for the size? This seems to work for me and is faster than the implementation I originally had and I don't see why this wouldn't work in any situation.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 I don't think the `bitset` version even needs bitness-adaptiveness, having it still be 64 bit on a 32 bit platform wouldn't break it (unlike the 64bit intrinsic which just doesn't exist in 32bit mode)

Comment: Yeah I guess that's true, but if its adaptive maybe it'll continue to work when computers support 128 bits sometime in the distant future hahaha

Comment: BTW I just tried a different algorithm that is more cache-aware and it ran in 0.6 million µs (not even a very fancy one), but it also gave totally different results (not just a matter of scaling). IDK why. But, clearly this is nowhere near how fast it could be.

Comment: When you say cache aware do you mean just caching the twiddle factor calculations so if you run it a second time it doesn't need to recalculate them?

Comment: @tjwrona1992 I mean avoiding most of the huge passes over the entire array, by not going stage-by-stage, for example like using a depth-first order or Stockham (which also avoids the bit reversing stuff)

Comment: Oh man, that sounds like something I should really learn about. Do you have any example code? I'll start Googling around. Thanks again for all the good advice!

Comment: I've managed to come up with an iterative implementation of the Stockham FFT but it only marginally improved the runtime. It does however look a lot cleaner. When you say depth first are you referring to using a recursive approach?

Comment: @tjwrona1992 that's one option, in principle it should be possible to do it iteratively, I'm not sure how to work out the index arithmetic

Comment: I guess what I'm confused about is how would a depth first traversal speed things up in this situation? Don't the same number of calculations still need to be performed either way?

Comment: @tjwrona1992 yes but the difference is that the results of the small stages are often immediately reused when they are still cached, instead of computing them all at once which basically guarantees that most of them have been pushed out of the cache by the time they are used

Comment: Alright I'll look into a depth first approach, but I've already tried recursion and that seemed to actually perform worse so I'd have to figure out an iterative approach.

Comment: I agree that extracting the Real FFT takes a significant portion of the total time, but it still seems faster than simply adding a 0 valued complex part to the real input and running it through the complex FFT.

Answer (score 9):

- These lines:

  ```
  size_t N_stage = static_cast<size_t>(std::pow(2, stage));
  size_t W_offset = static_cast<size_t>(std::pow(2, stages - stage));
  ```

  should not use floating-point math because they can be inaccurate. Instead use pure integer arithmetic:

  ```
  size_t N_stage = static_cast<size_t>(1) << stage;
  size_t W_offset = static_cast<size_t>(1) << (stages - stage);
  ```
- Each iteration of your loop `for (size_t stage = 1; stage <= stages; ++stage)` will linearly traverse the entire vector once. But this is not optimal if you consider the memory hierarchy. It would be a large change in your code, but you could rework the memory access pattern so that you transform increasingly larger blocks. This technique is known as a [cache-oblivious algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache-oblivious_algorithm).
- As a matter of personal taste, I would do `using std::vector` and `using std::complex` because they are referred to so many times in the code.
- Size 2 and size 4 DFTs have trivial integer twiddle factors (without irrationals), so you could special-case them to save some multiplications. You can use the formulas above to special-case your outer loop when `stage = 1` (length-2 DFT) and `stage = 2` (length-4 DFT). I have a [working example](https://www.nayuki.io/page/fast-fourier-transform-in-x86-assembly) on another page.

  The DFT of the length-2 complex vector [x0, x1] looks like this:

  ```
  X0 = x0 + x1
  X1 = x0 - x1
  ```

  The DFT of the length-4 complex vector [x0, x1, x2, x3] looks like this:

  ```
  X0 = x0 + x1 + x2 + x3
  X1 = x0 - i*x1 - x2 + i*x3
  X2 = x0 - x1 + x2 - x3
  X3 = x0 + i*x1 - x2 - x*x3
  ```

  If a complex number is represented as a pair of real numbers in rectangular form, then multiplication by *i* is just a matter of swapping the real/imaginary parts and negating the correct part - so no multiplication or addition is needed for this operation.
- The famous FFTW library has a bunch of speedup techniques, and there are articles you can find online that talk about how they work.
- Overall your `FFTRadix2()` looks quite similar to [my](https://www.nayuki.io/page/free-small-fft-in-multiple-languages) [FftComplex.cpp](https://www.nayuki.io/res/free-small-fft-in-multiple-languages/FftComplex.cpp) `Fft::transformRadix2()`.

Comment: Thanks @Nayuki! There is a lot here so I will reply with a comment per bullet. I have done some refactoring already which took care of bullet 1.

Comment: bullet 2 is interesting and I'll have to do more research on that. I'm still fairly inexperienced when it comes to DSP algorithms, but I'm working my way through a book and learning a lot.

Comment: bullet 3 I agree, I will likely add using statements because it is a bit cumbersome haha

Comment: bullet 4, could you possibly elaborate on this? I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean by this but it sounds interesting

Comment: bullet 5, I actually stumbled across that library when I was part-way through writing mine and used it as a reference. It was VERY helpful! Thank you! :)

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what is the reason for the `temp %= static_cast<unsigned long long>(n) * 2;` line in your Bluestein FFT implementation? I've been working on a Bluestein implementation of my own and I can't quite figure out why that line is necessary.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 Regarding Bluestein, the modulo is useful because it makes floating-point trigonometry more accurate. Basically if you look at sin(0.1) versus sin(0.1 + 2*PI) when calculated on a computer, the former is more accurate due to finite floating-point precision. So I chose to do a reduction over integers (which is exact) before calling the trigonometric function.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to work inplace by utilizing the fact that std::complex has a predefined layout. Therefore you can actually cast between an array of double and an array of (half as many) complex numbers.

```
std::vector<std::complex<double>> a(10);
double *b = reinterpret_cast<double *>(a.data());
```

EDIT:

To be more clear I would write

```
span<std::complex<double>> x_p(reinterpret_cast<std::complex<double>*>(x.data()), x.size() / 2);
```

This works in both ways. To enable safe and modern features you should use a span object. Unfortunately `std::span` is only available in C++20 so you should either write your own (which is a nice exercise) or have a look at `abseil::span` or `gsl::span`.

The code to implement those is rather minimal. With that you can remove two copies from your code

Comment: Are you saying replace `vector` with `span`? I haven't used `span` before. I'll look into it!

Comment: No, A span is non-owning. But rather than copying the data into `x_p` you should create a `span` that reinterprests the data in `x` as an array of `std::complex`

Comment: Ahh I see, maybe I will implement another one that does it in place like that. But I would also like to have the option to do it out of place as well

Comment: Do any compilers already support C++20? I didn't think it was officially released yet

Comment: @tjwrona1992 have a look here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support

Comment: Is `reinterpret_cast` from `complex double*` to `double*` strict-aliasing UB, or does ISO C++ say that `complex T` and `T` are alias-compatible?  Either way it's safe in Visual C++ which allows any/all aliasing and pointer-casting type punning.  But I think the OP is trying to write portable code.

Comment: @PeterCordes there is the [array-oriented access](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex#Array-oriented_access) thing

Comment: @harold: interesting, yeah for `std::complex<double>` that does mean it's safe since C++11.  The cppref wording for C++ seems to imply that it's also safe to do that in C11 with `_Complex double`, but [the cppref page for C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/complex) doesn't mention that.  I didn't check the ISO standard.