# HOW can I optimize this FFT C++ Code without using external libraries?

Tags: c++, performance

I have this assignment with the goal of improving the performance and execution time of a FFT C++ code without the use of external libraries. The code is as following:

```
void FftCalculator::ButterflyFFT(std::complex<double> *a,
                             std::complex<double> *b,
                             std::complex<double> w) {
 auto U = *b * w;
 *b = *a - U;
 *a = *a + U;
 }
 
uint32_t FftCalculator::bitReverseSingle(uint32_t x) {
x = (((x & 0xaaaaaaaa) >> 1) | ((x & 0x55555555) << 1));
x = (((x & 0xcccccccc) >> 2) | ((x & 0x33333333) << 2));
x = (((x & 0xf0f0f0f0) >> 4) | ((x & 0x0f0f0f0f) << 4));
x = (((x & 0xff00ff00) >> 8) | ((x & 0x00ff00ff) << 8));
return ((x >> 16) | (x << 16));
}

void FftCalculator::FFT(std::complex<double> *a, const int m) {
for (int i = 0; i < (degree_ / 2); i++) {
int m_idx = i / m;
// base address
int t_idx = i % m;
std::complex<double> *a_x = a + 2 * m_idx * m + t_idx;
std::complex<double> *a_y = a_x + m;
std::complex<double> w = tw[m + t_idx];
ButterflyFFT(a_x, a_y, w);
} 
}

void FftCalculator::bitReverse(std::complex<double> *a) {
for (int i = 0; i < (degree_); i++) {
int logdegree_ = log2(degree_);
int degree_idx = i % degree_;
int revdegree_ = bitReverseSingle(degree_idx) >> (32 - logdegree_);
if (revdegree_ > degree_idx) {
  std::complex<double> temp = a[degree_idx];
  a[degree_idx] = a[revdegree_];
  a[revdegree_] = temp;
}
}
}
 // mode 1 for FFT and 2 for inverse
ComplexVec FftCalculator::GetTwiddle(int mode) {
ComplexVec twiddle(degree_);
twiddle[0] = {1.0, 0.0};
for (int i = 1; i < degree_; i *= 2) {
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
  twiddle[i + j] = {cos(M_PI * (double)j / (double)i),
                    sin(powf(-1.0, mode) * M_PI * (double)j / (double)i)};
}
}
return twiddle;
}

 void FftCalculator::ExecFFT(std::complex<double> *a) {
 auto twiddle_factor = GetTwiddle(1);
 bitReverse(a);
 for (int i = 1; i < degree_; i *= 2) {
 FFT(a, i);
 } 
 }
```

The execution time is 30 ms Aprox, so I don't know how much can this code be improved. The thing is i'm not too good on C++ so I don't know what can I do to improve the performance. I know there is some libraries to optimize FFT in C++ but I was told I cannot use them. If someone can help me, I'd be really grateful.

Thanks

Comment: [Don't cross post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69968623/how-to-optimize-fft-c-code-without-using-external-libraries). Pick one site, and delete the question on the other site.

Comment: I think we need to see the class definition, and how it's being used to have enough context to review this properly.

Comment: There is some code missing to make this compile. If you add that, I'll probably give it a real look. In the meantime you can [this review of a different FFT implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/226329/36018), several of the points of interest are probably going to be similar.

Comment: Why couldn't you use one of the available libraries?  Licence compatibility?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `float` instead of `double`.
2. Don't use `logdegree_ = log2(degree_)`, you can use `std::bit_width` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_width)
3. You can use `std::swap` to swap something
4. Change `mode` to template parameter typed `bool`. Replace `powf(-1.0, mode)` to `mode ? -1.0f : 1.0f`

There are also lots of other room to improve your code style, but I think that things are irrelevant to performance.

Comment: Float isn't necessarily faster then double. It depends on your system/cpu, and the added precission from double might be a requirement!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584637/double-or-float-which-is-faster